# How can I set process.env.VAR on my local machine using bash/zsh script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, environment-variables, zsh

and what is this command actually doing?

```
export VAR="My permanent variable"
```

I used this and was able to see that it was set by doing a:

```
printenv VAR
```

However, when I `console.log(process.env)` in Node I can not find it.  Here is the ouptut:

```
{
  USER: 'c',
  __CFBundleIdentifier: 'com.sublimetext.4',
  COMMAND_MODE: 'unix2003',
  LOGNAME: 'c',
  PATH: '/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin',
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jc2uZOHY77/Listeners',
  SHELL: '/bin/zsh',
  HOME: '/Users/c',
  __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: '0x1F5:0x0:0x0',
  TMPDIR: '/var/folders/tx/zyf0hzln2rn97yd61x50y9l80000gn/T/',
  XPC_SERVICE_NAME: '0',
  XPC_FLAGS: '0x0',
  LC_CTYPE: 'UTF-8',
  SSL_CERT_FILE: '/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Lib/python3/certifi/cacert.pem',
  OLDPWD: '/'
}
```

I would like to set the process.env.VAR directly in the bash/zsh ( I am using zshell.) and have access to it in my Node code.

Comment: following all the steps you mentioned I was not able to recreate this issue. Are you running the export command in the same terminal you are running the node script?

Answer (score 0):

It set env variable, however not persistent manner.

If you do

```sh
export MY_VAR=123 && node index.js
```

Assuming index.js will have `console.log(process.env)` you will get the output. But in different terminal windows it won't be visible/shared. To achieve that you need to add `export VAR=value` in [.bashrc](https://www.journaldev.com/41479/bashrc-file-in-linux#:%7E:text=bashrc%20file%20is%20a%20script,won%27t%20show%20the%20file.) file
and reload the content. (It means every time a new terminal is open it will set that value)

Since you use `zshell` it will be `.zshrc`.

1. Open/edit `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Add `export YOUR_VAR=your_value`
3. Save
4. Reload by running `zsh` or reopen terminal

Here are more details on how to do it for zsh. [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1613628/how-to-add-exports-to-zshrc)

Comment: I dont think you should be setting project specific env variables inside of your .zshrc

Comment: Well, that is another topic. What is recommended and what's not but according to the question he wants to set it permanently.

Comment: @n1md7 - I am in fact setting it in my `~/.zshrc` file, but am not seeing it show up in when I log `process.env` in node.  All my other shell functions, etc. work.

Comment: It is available in the shell itself but not inside my node code where I need it.

Comment: In Linux or Mac this steps should work just fine. Are you in windows subsystem? What os u use?

Comment: I'm on maOS running zhell and Node.  I'm using the sublime debugger to run snippets in Node.